# restoring mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of updating a live database, by adding new tables.

Is there a way, if these updates go wrong, to restore the original?

Thanks

Comment: If you aren't doing anything else than adding new tables, you should just be able to `DROP` them. (Of course, having too many backup copies is not a big issue but having too few is terrible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to be altering a live database, then you **really need to do a backup before you start**, ideally after you've removed access from any front-end web site, etc. so that there's no "active" database activity. (This is less of an issue if you use InnoDB rather than MyISAM tables, that said.) Additionally, you should ideally prevent all access to the database whilst you're carrying out an alterations, as otherwise changes may be lost if you have to roll the database back to its previous state.

To create a backup the easiest solution is to use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command line tool that's bundled with MySQL. This will create a text file that you can use the restore the database to its original state.

As a hint, you might want to take special notice of the "[--add-drop-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-table)" option as this will prove useful if you want to stomp over whatever's there with the contents of the backup file. (N.B.: This will of course wipe out **ALL** the "current" data.)

Finally, if you're going to be making any significant changes then you really want to:

1. Create a script that carries out all the required ALTERs, etc. (You can then execute the script from the command line via "`mysql < [text file name]`".)
2. Use `mysqldump` to dump the current contents of the database and then set up a **test** database with this data so you can ensure your changes actually work as expected.

Comment: I was thinking of backing up the database first, using 'mysqldump -u root -ppassword live_db | mysql -u root -ppassword backup_db'. I don't really want to wiping out any current data. I will be adding 4 tables to the live DB. So if something breaks, I need to restore the DB to how it was before these were added.

Comment: Right ok. I have the sql script with the CREATE table etc etc of the 4 new tables. I also have a backup of the DB and I have tested the Dscript, which added 4 tables. I guess my worry is, the live DB is 1GB. So I guess I'll have to disable the DB whilst I copy it...

Comment: @terrid25 - If you're only adding new tables (rather than altering existing ones), and it worked fine on a backup, then you should be fine to just go for it on the live DB. Otherwise, I'd be tempted to off-line the front-end(s) whilst you do the backup/updates as per my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. By doing a backup **first**..

Comment: +1 From me. (Couldn't resist the emphasis on the "first". Apologies.) :-)

Comment: +1 and extra credit to @middaparka for **strongly emphasizing** it :)

Comment: @middaparka: No need to apologize. :D